# Powershell script using RegEx to look for a pattern in one .txt and find line in a second .txt

Tags: regex, powershell, text

I have a real "headsmasher" on my plate.

I have this piece of script:

```
$lines = Select-String -List -Path $sourceFile -Pattern $pattern -Context 20

foreach ($id in $lines) {

    if (Select-String -Quiet -LiteralPath export.txt -Pattern "$($Matches[1]).+$($id.Pattern)") {

        }

    else {
    
        Select-String -Path $sourceFile -Pattern $pattern -Context 20 >> $duplicateTransactionsFile
    
        }
    }
```

but it is not working for me as I wanted it to.

I have two .txt files: "$sourcefile = source.txt" and "export.txt"

The source.txt looks like something like this:

```
Some text here ***********
------------------------------------------------
 F I N A L  C O U N T                  1 9 , 9 9

**************
** [0000123456]
ID Number:0000123456
Complete!
****************!
***********



Some other text here*******
------------------------------------------------
 F I N A L  C O U N T                    9 , 9 9

**********
** [0000789000]
ID Number:0000789000
Complete!
******************!
************
```

The export.txt is like this:

```
0000123456  19,99
0000555555  ,89
0000666666  3,05
0000777777  31,19
0000789000  9,99
```

What I am trying to do is look into source.txt and search for the number that I enter (spaced out in my case)

**e.g: "9,99" but only that. As you can see, the next number in the source.txt is "19,99" and it also contains "9,99" but I do not want it to be matched.*

and once I find the number, look for the next line in the source.txt that contains the text "ID Number:" then get the numbers right after the ":" Once I get those numbers after the ":", I want to now look into the export.txt and see if the numbers after the ":" are there and whether it has the "9,99" on the same line next to it but exactly "9,99" and nothing else lie "19,99", "29,99", and so on.

Then the rest is easy:

```
if (*true*) {
do this
}

else {
do that
}
```

Could you guys give me some love here and help a brother out?
I very much appreciate any help or hint you could share.

Best of wishes!

Comment: So in your example the only `ID Number:` that should be matched is the 2nd one because `F I N A L  C O U N T ` is 9,99?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Correct, I seem to have switched them around, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approach this like below:

```
# read the export.txt file and convert to a Hashtable for fast lookup
$export = ((Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\export.txt').Trim() -replace '\s+', '=') -join "`r`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData

# read the source file and split into multiline data blocks
$source = ((Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\source.txt' -Raw) -split '-{2,}').Trim() | Where-Object { $_ -match '(?sm)^\s?F I N A L  C O U N T' }

# make sure the number given is spaced-out
$search = (((Read-Host "Search for Final Count number") -replace '\s' -split '') -join ' ').Trim()
Write-Host "Looking for a matching item using Final Count '$search'"

# see if we can find a data block that matches the $search
$blocks = $source | Where-Object { $_ -match "(?sm)^F I N A L  C O U N T\s+$search\s?$" }
if (!$blocks) {
    Write-Host "No item in source.txt could be found with Final Count '$search'" -ForegroundColor Red
}
else {
    # loop over the data block(s) and pick the one that matches the search count
    $blocks | ForEach-Object {
        # parse out the ID
        $id = $_ -replace '(?sm).*ID Number:(\d+).*', '$1'
        # check if the $export Hashtable contains a key with that ID number
        if ($export.Contains($id)) {
            # check if that item has a value of $search without the spaces
            if ($export[$id] -eq ($search -replace '\s')) {
                # found it; do something
                Write-Host "Found a match in the export.txt" -ForegroundColor Green
            }
            else {
                # found ID with different FinalCount
                Write-Host "An item with ID '$id' was found, but with different Final Count ($($export[$id]))" -ForegroundColor Red
            }
        }
        else {
            # ID not found
            Write-Host "No item with ID '$id' could be found in the export.txt" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
}
```

---

If as per your comment, you would like the code to loop over the Final Count numbers found in the source.txt file instead of a user typing in a number to search for, you can shorten the above code to:

```
# read the export.txt file and convert to a Hashtable for fast lookup
$export = ((Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\export.txt').Trim() -replace '\s+', '=') -join "`r`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData

# read the source file and split into multiline data blocks
$blocks = ((Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\source.txt' -Raw) -split '-{2,}').Trim() | 
            Where-Object { $_ -match '(?sm)^\s?F I N A L  C O U N T' }

if (!$blocks) {
    Write-Host "No item in source.txt could be found with Final Count '$search'" -ForegroundColor Red
}
else {
    # loop over the data block(s)
    $blocks | ForEach-Object {
        # parse out the FINAL COUNT number to look for in the export.txt
        $search = ([regex]'(?sm)^F I N A L  C O U N T\s+([\d,\s]+)$').Match($_).Groups[1].Value
        # remove the spaces, surrounding '0' and trailing comma (if any)
        $search = ($search -replace '\s').Trim('0').TrimEnd(',')
        Write-Host "Looking for a matching item using Final Count '$search'"
        # parse out the ID
        $id = $_ -replace '(?sm).*ID Number:(\d+).*', '$1'
        # check if the $export Hashtable contains a key with that ID number
        if ($export.Contains($id)) {
            # check if that item has a value of $search without the spaces
            if ($export[$id] -eq $search) {
                # found it; do something
                Write-Host "Found a match in the export.txt with ID: $($export[$id])" -ForegroundColor Green
            }
            else {
                # found ID with different FinalCount
                Write-Host "An item with ID '$id' was found, but with different Final Count ($($export[$id]))" -ForegroundColor Red
            }
        }
        else {
            # ID not found
            Write-Host "No item with ID '$id' could be found in the export.txt" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Perfect lecture! The only thing I have to take care of now is the ",89" and integers in the export.txt and represent them as doubles in the export.txt so I can match them.

Comment: @Sv3n You could remove leading zeroes from `$search` with `$search = $search.Trim("0").Trim()` if that helps

Comment: Sure thing! What I did though is touch the `export.txt` with a `-replace " ,", " 0,"`. I have the `"0000442908 13"` type of lines as well and have to make them like `"0000442908 13,00"` or again manipulate the `$search`.

Comment: Awesome! Figured it out. I did a `$search.EndsWith(",")` to remove the comma after trimming the "0"-s out of the way. Not very pretty but works fine for me. All thanks to you @Theo
Best of wishes!

Comment: Hey Theo! I got a quick one:
Can I just take the number after the `F I N A L  C O U N T` and loop each and every final count in the `source.txt` instead of inputting the number myself? How do you do that? I appreciate your wisdom on this. Regards

Answer (score 1):

There are surely multiple valid ways to accomplish this. Here is my approach:

(See comments for explanations. Let me know if you have any questions)

```
param (
    # You can provide this when calling the script using "-Search 9,99"
    # If not privided, powershell will prompt to enter the value
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    $Search,
    
    $Source = "source.txt",

    $Export = "export.txt"
)

# insert spaces
$pattern = $Search.ToCharArray() -join " "

# Search for the value in the source file.
$found = $false
switch -Regex -File $Source {
    # This regex looks for something that is not a number,
    # followed by only whitespace, and then your (spaced) search value.
    # This makes sure "19,99" is not matched with "9,99".
    # You could use a more elaborate regex here, but for your example,
    # this one should work fine.
    "\D\s+$pattern" {
        $found = $true
    }

    "ID Number:(\d+)" {
        # Get the ID number from the match.
        $id = $Matches[1]

        # If the search value was found
        # (that means, this ID number is immediately followed by the search value)
        # we can stop looking.
        if ($found) {
            break
        }
    }
}

# quick check if the value was actually found
if (-not $found) {
    throw "Value $Search not found in $Source."
}

# Search for the id in the export file.
switch -Regex -File $Export {
    "$id\s+(\S+)" {
        # Get the amount value from the match
        $value = $Matches[1]

        # If the value matches your search...
        if ($value -eq $search) {
            # do this
        }
        else {
            # otherwise do that
        }

        break
    }
}
```

Note: You could additionally convert the values to `decimal` to account for different text representations when searching and comparing.